# How to add metroframework.dll in a setup project

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using the Metroframework UI in my .NET application. Now I want to create a setup file using, but my setup file is not enough to run my application due to the Metroframwork dependencies.

How can I resolve this issue?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You must add:

```
MetroFramework.dll
MetroFramework.Design.dll
MetroFramework.Fonts.dll
```

Since you add them as PROJECT reference, the setup will include them into your installation.